# Changing the CurrentUICulture at runtime using locbaml method

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

Using the locbaml method, I've created a new resource dll and am trying to programatically change the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture on the fly, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using the 'locbaml' metod you cannot switch languages on the fly, thus you have to setup Current[UI]Culture appropriately if needed before showing any UI.

Comment: I also want to know the reason why I cannot change it on the fly.